# 'W: Failed to fetch...' while updating

Tags: upgrade, updates

This is the output of the command `sudo apt-get update`. I can't update any packages with update manager either. So what is the problem and how can I fix it?

```
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise InRelease                                        
Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                                        
Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease                                
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                                            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg                               
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg                                      
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                                            
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                                      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release                                   
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release                                          
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                                          
Get:1 http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg [198 B]                                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                                          
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg                              
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release                                              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources                              
Get:2 http://dl.google.com stable Release                                                 
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                              
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                                          
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources                          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex               
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner TranslationIndex                         
Get:3 http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages [1,234 B]                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                                         
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release                                  
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                                   
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex                 
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main TranslationIndex                                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                                
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                                     
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources                               
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources                                 
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources                               
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                               
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en                 
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages                           
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages                         
Get:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex [3,706 B]                
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex                      
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex                      
Get:5 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex [2,922 B]            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en                 
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources                             
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources                       
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources                         
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages                       
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages                 
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages                   
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en                   
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex                    
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex              
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex              
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex                
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en                        
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-de                        
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en                        
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-de                        
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en                      
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-de                      
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en                
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-de                
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en                
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-de                
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en                  
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-de                  
Err http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources                       
  404  Not Found
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en_US                        
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en                           
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-de      
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US               
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US          
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                  
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en             
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-de
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-de
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-de
Fetched 2,781 B in 1s (2,698 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/de.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Index

W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/de.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_i18n_Index

W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Try changing your mirror from **`software sources`** and try again.

Comment: Do you have  any problems accessing the internet on your computer?

Answer (score -1):

remove those files

```
 sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/de.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Index
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/de.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_i18n_Index
```

Comment: Can you explain why removing these files would solve the problem?

Comment: @Benvert Please, provide more details to your answer.